# Вставить если нет дубликатов mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Всем привет! 4й час ковыряю интернет безрезульатно =
Подскажите, пжлст, как составить запрос на добавление строки, но если еще НЕТ такой строки. Находил некоторые запросы - им нужен уникальный ключ, а его в таблице нет. Для примера

```
id  \ itemid
========
12  \  12
13  \  17
17  \  12
=========
```

Помогите пжст сформировать запрос который был запрещал добавить значение (17, 12 ) и добавил бы (17,13)

Comment: *им нужен уникальный ключ, а его в таблице нет* С учётом заявленных требований - он должен существовать. Создайте... и используйте тривиальное `INSERT IGNORE ...`

Comment: А почему нет уникального ключа, создайте его, один уникальный индекс на эти два поля (одновременно, оба поля в ключе)

Answer (score 2):

```
SET @id := 17;
SET @itemid := 12; -- или 13

INSERT INTO `table` (id, itemid)
SELECT @id, @itemid
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                   FROM `table` 
                   WHERE id = @id
                     AND itemid = @itemid
-- ну или так      WHERE (id, itemid) IN (@id, @itemid)
                 );
```

Comment: Спасибо! помогло и то и то. Буду теперь знать)